# Trying to Create React app and facing errors

Tags: reactjs

[cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd9IH.png)
I tried to uninstall the global version of the same as suggested by my cmd but I still get this error

Answer (score 0):

You can't **install** `create-react-app`. You can just run it like this:

```
npx create-react-app <appname>
```

[image: terminalss]
This will take a couple of minutes.

If you have an older version of `create-react-app` installed, you will have to uninstall it with:

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

And restart the terminal

Comment: "You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.2, which is behind the latest release (4.0.3).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App." This is what it's showing when I typed your command

Comment: yeah exactly try running `npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: "Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app" Now it shows this. I have already uninstalled the global but it still says the same

Comment: run this: `yarn global remove create-react-app` and then close the command line and open it again

Comment: Well it's still the same

Comment: did you restart the terminal?